# How do US agencies connect their APIs to Data.gov's registration system?

Tags: usa, data.gov, api

Data.gov contains over 190,000 data sets, but only a [select few](https://api.data.gov/docs/) are integrated into Data.gov's API key registration system. What is the process to integrate an existing API with data.gov as an API gateway and what are the benefits?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do the integration but the benefits are fairly obvious. You get to deal with a greatly "reduced" data set suitable for your needs, instead of having to sift through a vast amount of (mostly) useless data.

Comment: What about advantages to the data supplier?